# Show sliderInput only when fileInput is loaded into Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like the Slider to be shown only when the database via fileInput is loaded. In addition, as the maximum value (max) of the sliderInput, I would like it to be the total number of properties in the database, that is, it can vary depending on the database. Could you help me on this issue?
A test database can be downloaded from the following website: https://github.com/JovaniSouza/JovaniSouza5/blob/master/Example.xlsx

The executable code is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(rgdal)

function.cl<-function(df,k){
  
  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 
  
  #all cluster data df1 and specific cluster df_spec_clust
  df1<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  df1$cluster<-as.factor(clusters)
  
  #Colors
  my_colors <- rainbow(length(df1$cluster))
  names(my_colors) <- df1$cluster
  
  #Scatter Plot for all clusters
  g <- ggplot(data = df1,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, color=cluster)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4) +
    scale_color_manual("Legend", values = my_colors)
  plotGD <- g
  
  
  return(list(
    "Plot" = plotGD
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      fileInput("data", h3("Excel import")), 
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 3),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))))
                        
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  v <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$data, {
    v$df <- read_excel(input$data$datapath)
  })
  
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({if (!is.null(v$df)) {
    function.cl(v$df,input$Slider)
  }
  })
  
  
  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You could use `uiOutput` and `renderUI` to create a sliderInput only if the data loaded is not null. If you need more help, please include a reproducible dataset to your example, links are problematic because they can be broken in the future. Also, you should consider reducing your example because there is a lot of unnecessary stuff for your question.

Comment: You could also hide and show your inputs using shinyjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achived via the `uiOutput` and `renderUi` functions. `uiOutput` puts a placeholder in the UI which is filled via `renderUi` when the User has loaded a dataset.

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(
    theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
    "Cl",
    tabPanel(
      "Solution",
      fileInput("data", h3("Excel import")),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          uiOutput("slider")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$slider <- renderUI({
    req(input$data)
    sliderInput("Slider", h5(""), min = 2, max = max_k(), value = 3, step = 1)
  })
  
  v <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$data, {
    v$df <- read_excel(input$data$datapath)
  })
  
  max_k <- reactive({
    req(input$data)
    nrow(v$df)
  })

  Modelcl<-reactive({
    req(input$data)
    req(input$Slider)
    function.cl(v$df, input$Slider)
  })
  
  
  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
  
  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer! It worked, I would now just like to know how to insert the maximum sliderInput, be the amount of properties in my database, you know? I left it as default 4 in the code, but in fact, I would like the code to be identified from the amount of database properties that I will insert. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi @Jose. I just edited my code. If I got you right the maximum is the number of rows in your df. Based on this assumption I added an reactive ´max_k` which return the number of rows of the input dataset and which is used to set the max value in the sliderInput.

Comment: Thank you very much friend!

Comment: Last doubt in relation to the previous answer. If my sliderInput was in the ```ui``` and not ```server``` ,what would you enter for the max value of sliderInput??

Comment: (: In that case you can add `observeEvent(input$data, {
    updateSliderInput(session, "Slider", max = nrow(v$df))
  })` to the server function which updates teh maximum value as soon as a dataset is loaded. BTW: See https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html. Just worked through this chapter in the afternoon.

Comment: Hi, Stefan. I did it the way it did, it worked perfectly for excel data. However, I made input for shapefile data too, but ```max = nrow (v$df))``` didn't work for shapefile. Would you know how to solve it?

Comment: Hi @Jose. I'm not an expert on geospatial data. But if you read your shp-file via rgdal::readOGR you can check the number of features via nrow(shp@data) or dim(shp)[[1]]. So you can add an if-condition to first check the type of input data and depending on that to get the number of rows or features

Comment: Ah Ok, perfect! Thanks again stefan.

Comment: Hi, could you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63003756/remove-slider-when-selecting-an-option-in-shiny